# I want to create buttons on random times - Android

Tags: java, android, oncreate

I'm trying to make a simple bubbles game, I'm supposed to make 10 bubbles appear randomly on the screen for 3 seconds each. Whenever the user touches a bubble he has made it disappear and earns a point.
The problem now is that I can t show the bubbles randomly in time, I've tried to use `Thred.sleep()` in a for loop but it make all the application wait until looping ends and then it shows all the 10 bubbles. 
Here is the java code:
**NB: please check the *'generateButtons'* methode**

```
package com.adil.bullegame;


import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;
import static java.lang.Thread.sleep;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int bubblesNumber ;
    static int clickedBubbles=0;
    TextView text1;
    private static String in;
    private static final String FORMAT = "%02d:%02d:%02d";

    int seconds , minutes;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        CountDownTimer start = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) { // adjust the milli seconds here

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                text1.setText("" + String.format(FORMAT,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                showSimplePopUp();
                clickedBubbles=0;
            }
        }.start();


        // dynamic number of bubbles
        in =null;
        try{
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("file.txt");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            in = new String(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // bubblesNumber = parseInt(in);

        generateButtons(10);
    }

    private void generateButtons(int nbr)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i< nbr ; i++)
        {
            createButton();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }





            private void createButton() {

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);

            final Button myButton = new Button(this);
            layout.addView(myButton); ;

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams absParams =
                (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)myButton.getLayoutParams();

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;


        Random r = new Random();


        absParams.leftMargin =  r.nextInt(width-150) ;
        absParams.topMargin =  r.nextInt(height-150);
        myButton.setLayoutParams(absParams);


        myButton.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                                { public void run()
                                    { myButton.setVisibility(View.GONE); } }, 3000);

        //new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
         //  @Override
       //     public void run() {
           //       ((LinearLayout)myButton.getParent()).removeView(myButton);
         //      myButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       //     }
     //   }, 3000);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                clickedBubbles++;
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });



    }

    private void showSimplePopUp() {

        AlertDialog.Builder gameOver = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        gameOver.setTitle("GameOver");
        gameOver.setMessage("You clicked "+ clickedBubbles + " bubbles");
        gameOver.setPositiveButton("restart",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,  MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }

                });


        AlertDialog dialog = gameOver.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

}
```

**NB: please check the *'generateButtons'* methode**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application if freezing because your are calling sleep function on main UI thread. there are number of ways to solve this issue.

try the following method

```
private void generateButton(final int numberOfButtons) {
         new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 createButton();
                 if((numberOfButtons-1)>0){
                     generateButton(numberOfButtons-1);
                 }
             }
         }, 2000);
    }
```

Comment: #Sahil_Manchanda  Thank you very much it worked for me.

Comment: @AdilSaadi glad it helped